# How to use regex substitute using different capture and match strings?

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I want the `regex` machine to look for a certain pattern, and then only replace a subset of that pattern.  The strings look like this:

```
string1 = 'r|gw|gwe|bbbss|gwe | s'
```

And, I want to replace some of the strings using a `regex` like this:

```
re.sub('\|(gw.*)\|','nn',string1)
```

So, I want to *look for*  the  stuff between the `|`'s, but I only want replace what's between them, and not the entire `|(gw.*)|`.

Is there a concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain the pipe characters and match overlapping context, you need to use lookaround assertions. Because `*` is a greedy operator, it will consume as much as possible.

In this case you can use a negated character class or `*?` to prevent greediness.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\|)gw[^|]*(?=\|)', 'nn', s)
'r|nn|nn|bbbss|nn| s'
```

Or you could take a more general approach perhaps:

```
>>> '|'.join(['nn' if i.startswith('gw') else i for i in s.split('|')])
'r|nn|nn|bbbss|nn| s'
```

Comment: For example:  Before replacement:  `gw | gwe |  ab \r\n gwe | gwb | hu \r\n | gw | gw `.   After replacement:  `nn|nn|  ab \r\nnn|nn| hu \r\n |nn|nn `.   So, the line breaks are maintained, but the strings before and after the line breaks are treated the same as if they were between the pipes.